# Nested asynchronous listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

There are levels in order as Firebase Document. I want to list them and get the sub-steps in each level in the correct order.But each time it comes in a different order. I want:

Level1 / step1

Level1 / step2

Level2 / step1

Level2 / step2

Level 3 /step1

Level3 /step 2 etc.

Although I have ordered with order, sometimes the data in the 2nd and sometimes 3rd row comes up.

The code I wrote:

```
    db.collection("levels").orderBy("order",Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
    val documents = querySnapshot.documents

    for (document in documents){
        val level = document["level"].toString()

        db.collection("levels").document(level).collection("step").orderBy("order",Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener { qs->
                val documentqs =qs.documents
            for (documentq in documentqs){
                val step=documentq["step"].toString()
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to get sample data, since your code appears to be right, this could be a problem with the string sorting, assuming that the data is all string, so checking the actual data would make it easier to spot the issue.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is still in the wrong order in nested listener.

Comment: @freud in that case, could you share a couple of sample documents so we can try to replicate what is happening?